# QWebView not displaying PDF

Tags: python, pdf, pyqt, pyqt4, qwebview

I am new to PyQt4. My problem is when I use QWebView to display a pdf file it doesn't display - but no error or anything. I even added "file:///" to the file path and enabled the pdf viewer plugin. Has anyone here encountered this problem?

Here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebView()
web.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
web.show()
web.load(QUrl("sample.pdf")) # Change path to actual file. 

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Also please read the recommendations of [ask] and pass the [tour]

Comment: yeah will read  definitely read that thanks. i also edited my question thanks again